# How is the feedback separated in the block diagram given below?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, block-diagram

How is the feedback separated in step 3 ? I can understand step 1 and 2 but not step 3.

[image: The question is on the left and a part of the solution is on the right]

Comment: Are we done here? Do you follow the explanation I gave?

Comment: Finally it clicked me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: -

[image]

Hopefully that should be clear.